# Well-formness or Well-formedness

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Which of the titular phrase is the correct one? I find usages for both of them.

> **Well-formedness** is the quality of a clause, word, or other linguistic element that conforms to the grammar of the language of which it is a part.

and

> ...within the final applicative expression, to check the **well-formness** of French negative construction.

Comment: I do not think **well-formness** is a word. Where have you found it like this? Any place that is reputable?

Comment: *Well-formness* is not correct. This comes from a [source](https://books.google.com/books?id=6aom9gQuWR8C&pg=PA265&lpg=PA265&dq=%22to+check+the+well-formness+of+French+negative+construction.%22&source=bl&ots=xdxYtpPorD&sig=WrpgddP9eTywPGbv8rKlKRyn4B8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjuoantiZDSAhVo0FQKHUiYAMQQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22to%20check%20the%20well-formness%20of%20French%20negative%20construction.%22&f=false) full of ill-formed English.

Comment: :(( for the low quality question!

Answer (score 1):

**Well-formness** is incorrect. As StoneyB points out, it comes from *Combinatorial Categorial Grammar for Computer-Assisted Machine Learning*, which, ironically, appears to be filled with grammar and spelling errors; I spotted at least three on that page alone.

In general English, any word of the form *X-ness* can be read as "the extent to which X is exemplified"*. For example, *the wetness of a towel*, *the emptiness of space*. In these cases, *X* denotes a *property*, so its part of speech has to be that of an adjective. "Well-formed" is an adjective; "well-form" is nonsense.

*There are exceptions. "Likeness" and "witness" have different etymologies, for example.